# Looping Through Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a dictionary and append to a string- here is the code:

```
mylist= {'name':'james', 'age': '23', 'time': 'next'}
myquery = "select * from players where"
for k, v in mylist.items(): 
    myquery += "%s=%s and" % (k, v),

print myquery
```

This is prints `'select * from maintable where age=23 and name=jame and time=next and'`
My problem is that there is an 'and' at the end of that result.

How do I run that for loop without having that last and?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`str.join()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join strings together with an `' and '` delimiter:

```
myquery = "select * from players where {}".format(
    ' and '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in mylist.iteritems()))
```

Demo:

```
>>> mylist= {'name':'james', 'age': '23', 'time': 'next'}
>>> "select * from players where {}".format(
...     ' and '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in mylist.iteritems()))
'select * from players where age=23 and name=james and time=next'
```

However, it looks as if you are building a SQL query; don't interpolate the values in that case, use SQL parameters instead:

```
myquery = "select * from players where {}".format(
    ' and '.join('{}=?'.format(k) for k in mylist))
```

and then use `cursor.execute(myquery, mylist.values())` to pass the parameters to the database adapter.

Check what format your database adapter uses; some use `%s` (C sprintf style) and others use `?` as placeholders.

Comment: And sqlite3 (and some others) support `:name` instead/in addition to `%(name)s` style parameter escaping

Answer (score 2):

At  the end of the for loop add this statement, which removes the and from the query statement.

```
if myquery.endswith('and'):
   myquery = myquery[:-3]
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, thanks for the code sample, it's nice and short and did help.